# sudo alternative which supports PCRE

Tags: linux, command-line

I am missing regular expressions (PCRE syntax) in the linux tool `sudo`.

The solutions provided here do not satisfy me:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/533951/wildcards-in-sudoers-rule

Is there an alternative to `sudo` which supports regular expressions?

Required features:

- support for linux
- provide regular expressions for defining allowed commands
- open source